# Extreme Values of $f(P)$ When $P$ Lies Inside a Triangle with Vectices $A$,$B$, $C$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q:$P(x,y)$ given point lie inside or on the boundary of triangle $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

Find maximum and minimum $f(a,b,c)$

$$f(P)=\vec{PA}\cdot \vec{PB}+\vec{PB}\cdot \vec{PC}+\vec{PC}\cdot \vec{PA}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rewrite $f$ in terms of position vectors. For this purpose consider the following

$$\eqalign{
  & f = \overrightarrow {PA} .\overrightarrow {PB}  + \overrightarrow {PB} .\overrightarrow {PC}  + \overrightarrow {PC} .\overrightarrow {PA}   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PA} .\overrightarrow {PB}  = \left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow A } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow B } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PB} .\overrightarrow {PC}  = \left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow B } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow C } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PC} .\overrightarrow {PA}  = \left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow C } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow P  - \overrightarrow A } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow A } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A  \cr} $$

Hence, you may have

$$f = 3\overrightarrow P .\overrightarrow P  - 2\overrightarrow P .\left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right) + \left( {\overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A } \right)$$

Now compute the gradient vector and hessian matrix of $f$ to find

$$\eqalign{
  & \nabla f = 6\overrightarrow P  - 2\left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf{H}} = \nabla \nabla f = 6{\bf{I}} \cr} $$

As you see, at the critical point the gradient is zero

$$\nabla f = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\overrightarrow P  = {1 \over 3}\left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right)$$

but since the hessian matrix is positive definite you have a local minimum. But this is a quadratic form and hence the local minimum is the global minimum. Finally, you may conclude that the minimum of $f$ happens when $\overrightarrow P $ is at the centroid of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite my friend H. R's answer and reach to solution by simpler math. First you should notice that f is a function of $\overrightarrow P$ not a,b,c ! you want to find appropriate vector $\overrightarrow P$ for fixed triangle.
$$\eqalign{
  & f\left( {\overrightarrow P } \right) = \overrightarrow {PA} .\overrightarrow {PB}  + \overrightarrow {PB} .\overrightarrow {PC}  + \overrightarrow {PC} .\overrightarrow {PA}   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PA} .\overrightarrow {PB}  = \left( {\overrightarrow A  - \overrightarrow P } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow B  - \overrightarrow P } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PB} .\overrightarrow {PC}  = \left( {\overrightarrow B  - \overrightarrow P } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow C  - \overrightarrow P } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C   \cr 
  & \overrightarrow {PC} .\overrightarrow {PA}  = \left( {\overrightarrow C  - \overrightarrow P } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow A  - \overrightarrow P } \right) = {\left| {\overrightarrow P } \right|^2} - \left( {\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow A } \right).\overrightarrow P  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A  \cr} $$

Hence, you may have

$$f\left( {\overrightarrow P } \right) = 3\overrightarrow P .\overrightarrow P  - 2\overrightarrow P .\left( {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right) + \left( {\overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A } \right)$$
or
$$f\left( {\overrightarrow P } \right) = 3\left( {\overrightarrow P  - {1 \over 3}\left({\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C}\right) } \right).\left( {\overrightarrow P  - {1 \over 3}\left({\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C}\right) } \right)-{1 \over 3}\left({\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C}\right).\left({\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C}\right) + \left( {\overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A } \right)$$
or
$$f\left( {\overrightarrow P } \right) =3 {\left| {\overrightarrow P  - {1 \over 3}\left({\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C}\right) } \right|^2}-{1 \over 3}{\left| {\overrightarrow A  + \overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow C } \right|^2}+\left( {\overrightarrow A .\overrightarrow B  + \overrightarrow B .\overrightarrow C  + \overrightarrow C .\overrightarrow A } \right)$$
Finally, you conclude easily that the minimum of $f$ happens when $\overrightarrow P $ is at the centroid of the triangle. (last two sentences are constant and first one is always equal or greater than zero.)

Comment: Nice manipulation! Can you tell when $f$ is maximum? I was unable to clarify this in my answer since it needed to solve a constrained optimization problem and I was lazy to do that. However, geometrical intuition says that it will happen when $\overrightarrow P $ is at one of vertices of the triangle.

Comment: take it easy man. see last equation. you should choose point with maximum distance to centroid, that's it. it is unique iff triangle has no pair of side with same leinght.

Comment: You are right. In the form you wrote $f$ it is easy to see that. However, in my approach it's not that much easy to show! So I confess that your formulation is much easier and maybe better to solve the problem. Cheers! :)
You may add thorough explanations to your answer for the maximum and remove the repeated parts of it.